# Error "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists"

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I am trying to run Jenkins in Tomcat inside Ubuntu. I have installed Java and Tomcat successfully on Ubuntu. I am able to deploy Jenkins in Tomcat successfully. I am getting this error when I  click on /Jenkins:

I get redirected to http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ and see this error. I am new to all this. I am attaching image of my tomcat manager console for reference:

[image]